# Error trying to edit a user on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting a project with laravel, and I'm having a problem when I try to edit a user.

It always return the "QueryException" as if I didn't pass the user ID, but I used the default layout for my Model, so my URL is something like /users/1/edit.

[image: QueryException Error]

This is how my route is defined:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('users', 'CtrUsers');
```

This is the way I get the edit URL:

```
href="{{route('users.edit', $user)}}"
```

(the $user is set inside a foreach loop)

And this is my edit function:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

And something strange is that when I enter the URL /users/edit/1 (with de ID in the end), IT stops returning the QueryException, but returns "NotFoundHttpException".

[image: NotFoundHttpException]

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: you need to check your rewrite rules/ pretty url setting

Comment: can u please post the error message

Comment: The correct url is /users/1/edit. Why are you passing $role in the route() function for the href? Is that an instance of User and you called it $role? Or is it a role? The edit method expects a User

Comment: Sorry, the correct is $user, I wrote it wrong here

Comment: Did you bind correct model to your route params? Please add your web.php routes file and roles table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was rebuild my migrations changing the names of my tables ID's to just "ID", becouse I noticed that the errors were allways because the system doesn't find any column named usr_id.

Answer (score 0):

change your controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

Edited again

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::where('usr_id',$id)->findOrFail();
        return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this, and now I got another error:
http://imgur.com/a/PzChk

I believe that this error is about a user.id defined somewhere I don't know, because I defined my User ID like User.usr_id on my migration and Model.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the variable name which you have used for route model binding. Both variable names: the one which is on the route and another from the action parameter must match.

You can check the route info using `php artisan route:list` command.

So you have two options, either change the `users` variable name to `user` in the route like:

```
Route::resource('user', 'CtrUsers');
```

OR

You can change the variable name from `user` to `users` in the action parameter like:

```
public function edit(User $users)
{
    return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

For more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding